# Maximal & closed frequent -- Answer Included

Tags: data-mining, dataset, association-rules

$$My \ \ dataset:$$
$$1: A,B,C,E$$
$$2:A,C,D,E$$ 
$$3:\ \ \ \ \  B,C,E$$
$$4:A,C,D,E$$
$$5:\ \ \ \ C, D, E$$
$$6: \ \ \ \ A, D,E$$

I want to find out the **maximal frequent item sets** and the **closed frequent item sets**.

- Frequent item set $X ∈ F$ is **maximal** if it does not have  any
  frequent supersets.
- Frequent item set X ∈ F is **closed** if it has no superset  with the
  same frequency

---

So I counted the occurrence of each item set.

```
{A} = 4 ;  {B} = 2  ; {C} = 5  ; {D} = 4  ; {E} = 6

{A,B} = 1; {A,C} = 3; {A,D} = 3; {A,E} = 4; {B,C} = 2; 
{B,D} = 0; {B,E} = 2; {C,D} = 3; {C,E} = 5; {D,E} = 3

{A,B,C} = 1; {A,B,D} = 0; {A,B,E} = 1; {A,C,D} = 2; {A,C,E} = 3; 
{A,D,E} = 3; {B,C,D} = 0; {B,C,E} = 2; {C,D,E} = 3

{A,B,C,D} = 0; {A,B,C,E} = 1; {B,C,D,E} = 0
```

---

Min_Support set to $50%$ // Very important. Thanks steffen for reminding of that.

Does **maximal** = $\{{A,B,C,E\}}$ ?

Does **closed** = $\{{A,B,C,D\}} \ and \ \{{B,C,D,E\}}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a slightly extended definition in this [source](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jin/DM08/FIM.pdf) (which includes a good explanation). Here is a more reliable (published) source: [CHARM: An efficient algorithm for closed itemset mining by Mohammed J. Zaki and Ching-jui Hsiao](https://www.siam.org/proceedings/datamining/2002/dm02-27ZakiM.pdf).

According to this source:

- An itemset  is  closed      if  none  of      its  immediate  supersets  has      the      same       support  as  the  itemset
- An  itemset  is  maximal  frequent      if  none  of  its  immediate  supersets  is  frequent

**Some remarks:**

- It is necessary to set a **min_support** (support = the number of item sets  containing the subset of interest divided by the number of all itemsets) which defines which itemset is **frequent**. An itemset is frequent if its support >= min_support.
- In regards to the algorithm, only itemsets with min_support are considered when one tries to find the maximal frequent and closed itemsets.
- The important aspect in the definition of **closed** is,  that it does not matter if an immediate superset exists with more support, only immediate supersets with exactly the same support do matter.
- maximal frequent => closed => frequent, but not vice versa.

**Application to the example of the OP**

Note:

- Did not check the support counts
- Let's say min_support=0.5. This is fulfilled if min_support_count >= 3

```
{A} = 4  ; not closed due to {A,E}
{B} = 2  ; not frequent => ignore
{C} = 5  ; not closed due to {C,E}
{D} = 4  ; not closed due to {D,E}, but not maximal due to e.g. {A,D}
{E} = 6  ; closed, but not maximal due to e.g. {D,E}

{A,B} = 1; not frequent => ignore
{A,C} = 3; not closed due to {A,C,E}
{A,D} = 3; not closed due to {A,D,E}
{A,E} = 4; closed, but not maximal due to {A,D,E}
{B,C} = 2; not frequent => ignore
{B,D} = 0; not frequent => ignore
{B,E} = 2; not frequent => ignore
{C,D} = 3; not closed due to {C,D,E}
{C,E} = 5; closed, but not maximal due to {C,D,E}
{D,E} = 4; closed, but not maximal due to {A,D,E}

{A,B,C} = 1; not frequent => ignore
{A,B,D} = 0; not frequent => ignore
{A,B,E} = 1; not frequent => ignore
{A,C,D} = 2; not frequent => ignore
{A,C,E} = 3; maximal frequent
{A,D,E} = 3; maximal frequent
{B,C,D} = 0; not frequent => ignore
{B,C,E} = 2; not frequent => ignore
{C,D,E} = 3; maximal frequent

{A,B,C,D} = 0; not frequent => ignore
{A,B,C,E} = 1; not frequent => ignore
{B,C,D,E} = 0; not frequent => ignore
```

Comment: changed min_support=0.5 <=> min_support_count=3 and changed application to example accordingly.

Comment: Use APRIORI, and you can save a lot of counting and constructing itemsets...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I know APRIORI ... I stepped over the itemsets manually to explain the concept of closed and maximal frequent itemsets as detailed as possible, since this was the source of confusion of the OP (IMHO).

Comment: But yeah, I should have skipped the sets where subsets are already not frequent.

Comment: @steffen Hi, I'm a bit confused, why {C,D} = 3 is not closed due to {C,D,E} , but {C,E} = 5 is closed?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on the APRIORI algorithm. It avoids unneccessary itemsets by clever pruning.

```
{A} = 4 ;  {B} = 2  ; {C} = 5  ; {D} = 4  ; {E} = 6
```

B is not frequent, remove.

Construct and count two-itemsets (no magic yet, except that `B` is already out)

```
{A,C} = 3; {A,D} = 3; {A,E} = 4; 
{C,D} = 3; {C,E} = 5; {D,E} = 3
```

All of these are frequent (notice that all that had `B` cannot be frequent!)

Now use the prefix rule. ONLY combine itemsets starting with the same n-1 items.
Remove all, where any subset is not frequent. Count the remaining itemsets.

```
{A,C,D} = 2; {A,C,E} = 3; {A,D,E} = 3; 
{C,D,E} = 3
```

Note that `{A,C,D}` is not frequent. As there is no shared prefix, there *cannot* be a larger frequent itemset!

Notice how much less work I did!

For maximal / closed itemsets, check subsets / supersets.

Note that e.g. `{E}=6`, and `{A,E}=4`. `{E}` is a subset, *but* has higher support, i.e. it is closed but not maximal. `{A}` is neither, as it does not have higher support than `{A,E}`, i.e. it is *redundant*.